# Finding highest and subsequent values in a range

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

I have the below code which is supposed to find the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and 4th highest values in a range.

It is currently very basic, and I have it providing the values in a MsgBox so I can confirm it is working.

However, it only finds the highest and second highest values.  The third and fourth values are returned back as 0.  What am I missing?

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Dim firstVal As Double, secondVal As Double, thirdVal As Double, fourthVal As Double

Set rng = [C4:C16]

For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value > firstVal Then firstVal = cell.Value
    If cell.Value > secondVal And cell.Value < firstVal Then secondVal = 
    cell.Value
    If cell.Value > thirdVal And cell.Value < secondVal Then thirdVal = 
    cell.Value
    If cell.Value > fourthVal And cell.Value < thirdVal Then fourthVal = 
    cell.Value
Next cell

MsgBox "First Highest Value is " & firstVal
MsgBox "Second Highest Value is " & secondVal
MsgBox "Third Highest Value is " & thirdVal
MsgBox "Fourth Highest Value is " & fourthVal

End Sub
```

Comment: Another way would be to sort the range and then pick up your values :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Application.WorksheetFunction.Large():

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Dim firstVal As Double, secondVal As Double, thirdVal As Double, fourthVal As Double

Set rng = [C4:C16]


firstVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(rng,1)
secondVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(rng,2)        
thirdVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(rng,3)
fourthVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(rng,4)

MsgBox "First Highest Value is " & firstVal
MsgBox "Second Highest Value is " & secondVal
MsgBox "Third Highest Value is " & thirdVal
MsgBox "Fourth Highest Value is " & fourthVal

End Sub
```

Comment: @Scott Cramer I'll add one more caveat...what I really want to do is store the string in the cell to the left (IE in column B) of the (1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th) value in a variable.  So offset (0, -1).  How do I get the offset in there correctly?

Comment: @sbagnato Then use Match to find the value in the list and use `rng(i).offset(0,-1)` where i is the long returned by the `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match`.  Try with those hints, if you cannot make it work then ask a new question.

Comment: I have a question regarding this topic. I would also like to get the Range reference of the highest values. Can you give me an advice how this can be done?

Thanks.

Comment: please create your own post with your own question and needed information.  @MrZH6  Asking a new question on a question that is nearly 2 years old is not the correct method to get an answer to a question.

Answer (score 2):

You have a better method suggested by [Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner) above. However, to answer your question, you are only returning a limited number of values because you are overwriting the values without shifting the original values to a lower rank.

```
Dim myVALs As Variant
myVALs = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

For Each cell In rng
    Select Case True
        Case cell.Value2 > myVALs(0)
            myVALs(4) = myVALs(3)
            myVALs(3) = myVALs(2)
            myVALs(2) = myVALs(1)
            myVALs(1) = myVALs(0)
            myVALs(0) = cell.Value2
        Case cell.Value2 > myVALs(1)
            myVALs(4) = myVALs(3)
            myVALs(3) = myVALs(2)
            myVALs(2) = myVALs(1)
            myVALs(1) = cell.Value2
        Case cell.Value2 > myVALs(2)
            myVALs(4) = myVALs(3)
            myVALs(3) = myVALs(2)
            myVALs(2) = cell.Value2
        Case cell.Value2 > myVALs(3)
            myVALs(4) = myVALs(3)
            myVALs(3) = cell.Value2
        Case cell.Value2 > myVALs(4)
            myVALs(4) = cell.Value2
        Case Else
            'do nothing
    End Select
Next cell

Debug.Print "first: " & myVALs(0)
Debug.Print "second: " & myVALs(1)
Debug.Print "third: " & myVALs(2)
Debug.Print "fourth: " & myVALs(3)
Debug.Print "fifth: " & myVALs(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel wroksheetfuntion will be a better option for the task.This will allow the user to select the range and also will keep them posted on any range with invalid data. Another Double data type can be declared for Top4 value and msgbox for the same can also be updated. This will avoid any kind of error in the macro.

```
Sub top_three()

Dim Area As Range
Dim Tone As Double, Ttwo As Double, Tthree As Double

On Error GoTo Skip

Set Area = Excel.Application.InputBox("Select the Range", "Data Visulaization", 
Type:=8)

If Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Area) >= 3 Then

Tone = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Large(Area, 1)
Ttwo = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Large(Area, 2)
Tthree = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Large(Area, 3)

VBA.Interaction.MsgBox "Top 1: " & Tone & VBA.Constants.vbNewLine & _
"Top 2: " & Ttwo & VBA.Constants.vbNewLine & "Top 3:" & Tthree, Title:= _
"Top 3 values"

Else

VBA.Interaction.MsgBox "No Enough Data type to perform the task", vbInformation

End If

Skip:

End Sub
```