# Get Cell reference for TOP 3 numbers within a Range (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Range of Cells in Excel with numbers (Let's say `A1:Z1`) and I want to get three highest numbers. Answer to this part of the question I found here - [Finding highest and subsequent values in a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44551470/finding-highest-and-subsequent-values-in-a-range)

But I want also to get the cell reference of these values.

```
firstVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(rng,1)
secondVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(rng,2)        
thirdVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(rng,3)
```

Comment: Feeding the output of LARGE into a MATCH should get you what you want.

Comment: @TimWilliams - this would fail, if the values are the same.

Comment: I guess it's not clear what "fail" means when the values are the same?

Comment: @TimWilliams - it means that the result would be wrong. Try with a range with the following values - `7,8,8,1,2,1,1,1,1` and you would see that it will not give the top 3 cells, if match is used.

Comment: @Vityata - yes I understand that, and only meant that the implications for this particular use case are not fully-defined.

Comment: @TimWilliams - I see. I was doing some algorithm challenges today, thus going for the worst case scenario.

Comment: @Vityata - I think I'm mainly defending my lazy answer  ;-)

Comment: @TimWilliams - many people would do so, few would admit it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting the values, try looping through the range and assign range variables to these. Then print the addresses of the range variables:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim firstVal As Double
    Dim secondVal As Double
    Dim thirdVal As Double
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Worksheets(1).Range("A1:B10")

    With Application
        firstVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(rng, 1)
        secondVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(rng, 2)
        thirdVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(rng, 3)
    End With

    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim firstCell As Range
    Dim secondCell As Range
    Dim thirdCell As Range

    For Each myCell In rng
        If myCell.Value = firstVal And (firstCell Is Nothing) Then
            Set firstCell = myCell
        ElseIf myCell.Value = secondVal And (secondCell Is Nothing) Then
            Set secondCell = myCell
        ElseIf myCell.Value = thirdVal And (thirdCell Is Nothing) Then
            Set thirdCell = myCell
        End If
    Next myCell

    Debug.Print firstCell.Address, secondCell.Address, thirdCell.Address

End Sub
```

The check `firstCell Is Nothing` is done to make sure that in case of more than one top variable, the second one is assigned to the secondCell. E.g., if the range looks like this:

[image]

then the top 3 cells would be `A2, A3, A1`.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not very efficient but you can specify how many addresses to return:

```
Sub Tester()

    Debug.Print Join(Largest(ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Z1"), 3), ", ")

End Sub


Function Largest(rng As Range, howMany As Long)
    Dim rv(), n As Long, c As Range, lg
    ReDim rv(1 To howMany)
    n = 1
    Do
        lg = Application.Large(rng, n)
        For Each c In rng
            If c.Value = lg Then
                If IsError(Application.Match(c.Address, rv, 0)) Then
                    rv(n) = c.Address
                    n = n + 1
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next c
    Loop While n <= howMany
    Largest = rv
End Function
```